# VB dynamic sql query not working

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form5

    Dim CrystalReportViewer1 As Object

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If TextBox1.Text = "thulasi" Then
            Form3.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect password ! Try again", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Thulasi-Restaurent")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Me.Close()


        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim str As String
        str = "select * from billall where bdate between  #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date & "# and #" & DateTimePicker2.Value.Date & "# order by indate"

        Cn.Open()
        Dim adap As New OleDbDataAdapter(str, Cn)

        adap.Fill(ds, "billall")
        Dim doc1 As New ReportDocument
        doc1.Load("D:\billing\DuraiRestaurent\CrystalReport2.rpt")
        doc1.SetDataSource(ds)
        CrystalReportViewer1.CrystalReport2.ReportSource = doc1
        Cn.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

When trying to execute an `OleDBException` error occurs: "No value given for one or more required parameters". Can you help?

Comment: What database are you using, SQL, Orac;e, MySQL etc ?

Comment: Looks like it's an ACCESS database. Can you confirm if the field "indate" is a valid field on the table billall ?

Comment: Hi kelly i have indate in my db but unable to find the problem anyway i have sorted out by creating a new query in access db itself with sql view option in the table and its now working fine thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive this error it means that the Access Engine cannot correctly find one or more of your columns names or the whole table name.

To the OleDbDataAdapter I would say that you should use it like this (example):

```
 String command = "SELECT movieId, name, headActor, Director, ReleaseDate, lenghtMin " &
          "FROM Movies WHERE headactor =  ?"

 Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, connectionString);
 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", lastName)
```